# rudin's functional analysis query

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Theorem 10.18 corollary a). Rudin indicates that the fact the boundary of ${\sigma}_{A}(x)$ lies in the boundary of ${\sigma}_{B}(x)$, proves the statement  'if ${\rho}_{B}x$ is connected, then ${\sigma}_{A}(x)$=${\sigma}_{B}(x)$'. He also says that if ${\sigma}_{B}(x)$ is real, then ${\rho}_{B}x$ is connected. May someone please help me to understand these deductions.

Comment: It may be a good idea to define your terms here.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of Theorem 10.18 (b) states "Under these conditions, if $x \in A$, then $\sigma_A(x)$ is the union of $\sigma_B(x)$ and a (possibly empty) collection of bounded components of the complement of $\sigma_B(x)$."

If $\Omega_B = \mathbb{C}\setminus\sigma_B(x)$ is connected, then it has no bounded components (the only component being $\Omega_B$ itself).

Another way to see this is to look at the proof of 10.18 (b), where Rudin shows that $\Omega_A = \mathbb{C}\setminus\sigma_A(x) \subset \Omega_B$ and $\Omega_B$ contains no boundary points of $\Omega_A$. By Lemma 10.16, $\Omega_A$ is the union of all components of $\Omega_B$ that intersect $\Omega_A$. If $\Omega_B$ is connected, the only component is $\Omega_B$. So, we must have $\Omega_B \subset \Omega_A$, i.e., $\Omega_B = \Omega_A$ and so $\sigma_A(x) = \sigma_B(x)$.

The implication "if $\sigma_B(x) \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $\Omega_B$ is connected" follows from the fact that $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$ is connected for any $A \subsetneq \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma_B(x) \neq \mathbb{R}$ since $\sigma_B(x)$ is compact.